# Why is my notification listener service not starting?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, notification-listener

I'm trying to implement a `NotificationListenerService` in Android, but it's not starting.

MyNotificationService

```
public class MyNotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyNotificationService";

    private boolean mConnected = false;

    @Override
    public ComponentName startService(Intent service) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting Notification service");
        return super.startService(service);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListenerConnected() {
        super.onListenerConnected();
        Log.d(TAG, "Listener connected");
        mConnected = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListenerDisconnected() {
        super.onListenerDisconnected();
        Log.d(TAG, "Listener disconnected");
        mConnected = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
        Log.d(TAG, "Listener notification posted mConnected=" + mConnected);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);
        Log.d(TAG, "Listener notification posted mConnected=" + mConnected);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "mychannel";
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationService:MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d(TAG, "on create");
        createNotificationChannel();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.id.icon)
                .setContentTitle("contenttitle")
                .setContentText("contenttext")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.notify(1001, mBuilder.build());

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "received " + intent.getAction());
                Toast.makeText(context, intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new IntentFilter("android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"));
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "mychannelname", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("mychanneldescription");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fxnq76.notificationservice">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyNotificationService"
            android:label="MyNotificationServiceLabel"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The only log that prints is the on create one. It seems like the intent isn't even getting sent. As you can see I'm trying to receive and print it in the MainActivity, but that statement never prints.

I've tried manually sending the intent with `adb shell am start -a "android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"`, but I get

> Starting: Intent {
>   act=android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService } Error:
>   Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent {
>   act=android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService
>   flg=0x10000000 }

I've read the user needs to manually enable the notification permission, but when I go to the settings app, it doesn't ask for any notification related permissions. I tried adding, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />` to my manifest but it doesn't make a difference.

How do I get this notification listener service to run?

Comment: The Notification Access permission isn't under the Permissions menu. It's under `Settings>>Apps>>Special Access`.

Comment: @TheWanderer Thank you. For anyone who comes to this thread in the future it was actually under `Settings >  Apps & Notifications > Advanced > Special app access > Notification Access`.